# How to set an Alarm in an Android App based on a server's current time?

Tags: android, calendar, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, alarm

I am building an Android application that sets an alarm based on my application's server time.

By comparing GMT and application server time am trying to create an alarm.

for example:   GMT = 10.30 am and server time = 4.30 am, so i need to set alarm after 1hour/2hour from server time.

Example code:

```
Calendar calender=Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
calender.set(Calendar.HOUR,-6); // my server running time is less than 6 hours of GMT time.
calender.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
calender.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
```

can anyone has idea on how to set alarm
**How do I set the alarm?**

Comment: Can you reformat your question so that it is clearer and easily comprehensible?

Comment: how to set the alarm based on GMT time

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, here is what you need to do.

1. Get Calendar object for GMT timezone.
2. Get current time.
3. Set current time to your calendar object.
4. Finally, add one hour to this calendar object.

> Here is how you can achieve this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(currentTime);
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: if i followed this  working as a server time only and set the alarm time,unable to work  the alarm.

Comment: @RameshC: Can you please elaborate **unable to work the alarm.** ? What results do you see?

Comment: if is reduce server time from GMT time , an alarm suddenly fire,if  i do not  reduce the server time  and add minutes and seconds  an alarm is fire as for  proper time . thanks for reply..help me....

Comment: Are you saying that if you don't set the -6 hours for the HOUR field, it is working fine? I'm sorry, but I'm not able to understand what you're trying to say..

Comment: yes,if i don't set the -6 in hours field it is working,but if i add it  alarm will fire appln run time it self,(suddendly).

Comment: Can you login to this [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19132/java-and-android-era)